# What is the soundtrack in episode 735?

Tags: music, one-piece

What music track plays in one piece episode 735 at the end when fujitora Apologizes to the kingdom and the news spreads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://onepiecetracklist.com/#/3

"War Cry of the Marine Swordsmen"